# Update ProgressBar while reading large XML File (WPF)

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I have a WPF form in which i have added a progess bar at the bottom. The purpose of the program is to read xml and then update in to access. During the whole process, I want progress bar to update as XML is huge.

I am using XMLReader (please see code below). This code is triggered when button is clicked. Can someone please help how to update progress bar (in %) while xml is read?

I also want 2nd progress bar to get updated when the data is copied to Access and for this I have another function which get triggered from Button2.

```
    Dim ADCECounter As Integer = 0
    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
    Dim xReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xml_txtbox_2G.Text, settings)
    Dim ns As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("raml20.xsd")
    Dim ADCE_DT As New DataTable
    ADCE_DT = DataTables2G.Tables2G.ADCE_DT

    Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim elapstedtime As Double

    While (Not xReader.EOF)
        If xReader.Name <> "managedObject" Then
            xReader.ReadToFollowing("managedObject")
        End If
        If Not xReader.EOF Then
            Dim managedObject As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(xReader)
            If CType(managedObject.Attribute("class"), String) = "ADCE" Then
                Call XMLParse2G.XMLParse.ADCE(ADCE_DT, managedObject, ns)
                ADCECounter = ADCECounter + 1
            End If
        End If
    End While
```

Progress bar is declared in MainWindow.xaml (WPF).

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="20" Margin="2,2,2,2" Padding="2" />
```

Comment: Where is the progress bar declaration and code?

Comment: ProgressBar declaration is mentioned in the XAML (MainWindow.xaml).

Comment: But your code above doesn't show any attempt at coding to update the progress bar. How can we know where you are having issues if you have not tried a few things?

Comment: Hi AJD, i don't know how it can be used because XMLReader is reading the file (line by line) and it doesn't have any information of how many total lines are available in it. I can't calculate the percentage as the total lines are not known (also it number of total lines are variable in every xml file).  In order to  use the ProgressBar, i need to know the percentage of the progress (% of xml file that is read).  There was one method i tried of loading XML in to the memory but that give "Out of Memory" Error because usually my XML is huge in size (over 2GB).

Comment: Is there any method in XMLReader that gives the % of the file that is read already ?